# check first value/key in array when using in_array function

Tags: php

I have this array of values:

```
$col_names = array(
                   'Call For?' => 'assigned_to', 
                   'Message' => 'message', 
                   'Name' => 'caller_name', 
                   'Company Name' => 'caller_company', 
                   'Telephone' => 'caller_telephone'
                  );
```

I then use an in_array function to check if a value is in the above array:

```
if(in_array(trim(tdrows($node->childNodes)), $col_names)) {
```

I want to check the first value in the array, for example check `Call For?` rather than `assigned_to`

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Or better yet use `array_key_exists()`. This is much more efficient then retrieving the entire list of keys and doing an `in_array` lookup as suggested in sgt's answer:

```
if(array_key_exists(trim(tdrows($node->childNodes)), $col_names)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you `array_flip()` which will flip the array.

```
in_array(trim(tdrows($node->childNodes)), array_flip($col_names))
```

or if you dont need the values then try with `array_keys()` which will extract the keys only

```
in_array(trim(tdrows($node->childNodes)), array_keys($col_names))
```

Comment: Not the most efficient way to do it. If he only needs to check the existence of the key it's better to use `array_key_exists()`

Comment: yup.. it will be the most efficient. missed this.  :) will give you +1..@AlexLinte

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

to find if key exists or not. This is better than the [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) method